# Why is my list sometimes including false references in my PostgreSQL view?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have a problem on this view :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.v_izae_unites_foncieres_13
AS SELECT row_number() OVER () AS ogc_fid,
    foo.code_insee,
    foo.nompro,
    foo.adr_prop,
    foo.cp_prop,
    foo.ville_prop,
    foo.wkb_geometry,
    round(st_area(foo.wkb_geometry)::integer::numeric, 0) AS surface,
    concat(zae.numero_zae, '-', row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY zae.numero_zae ORDER BY zae.ogc_fid)) AS code,
    foo.refparc_liste,
    foo.numero_zae
   FROM ( SELECT faa.code_insee,
            faa.nompro,
            faa.adr_prop,
            faa.cp_prop,
            faa.ville_prop,
            faa.numero_zae,
            (st_dump(st_union(faa.wkb_geometry))).geom::geometry(Polygon,2154) AS wkb_geometry,
            array_agg(faa.refparc) AS refparc_liste
           FROM ( SELECT parcelles.ogc_fid,
                    parcelles.wkb_geometry,
                    parcelles.code_insee,
                    parcelles.nompro,
                    parcelles.adr_prop,
                    parcelles.cp_prop,
                    parcelles.ville_prop,
                    parcelles.refparc,
                    parcelles.numero_zae
                   FROM zae zae_1
                     JOIN LATERAL ( SELECT parcelles_ozae.ogc_fid,
                            parcelles_ozae.wkb_geometry,
                            parcelles_ozae.code_insee,
                            parcelles_ozae.nompro,
                            parcelles_ozae.adr_prop,
                            parcelles_ozae.cp_prop,
                            parcelles_ozae.ville_prop,
                            parcelles_ozae.refparc,
                            parcelles_ozae.numero_zae
                           FROM parcelles_ozae
                          WHERE st_contains(zae_1.wkb_geometry, st_pointonsurface(parcelles_ozae.wkb_geometry))) parcelles ON true) faa
          GROUP BY faa.nompro, faa.code_insee, faa.adr_prop, faa.cp_prop, faa.ville_prop, faa.numero_zae) foo
     JOIN zae ON foo.numero_zae::text = zae.numero_zae::text;
```

The objective of this view is to get data named 'unites_foncieres' made from entites in the table 'parcelles_ozae'.

The view works, but I have issues with the refparc_liste.

The refparc_liste is an aggregation of all the refparc oh the parcelles_ozae that constitute the unites_foncieres (the data created with the view).

Sometimes, my refparc_liste has several refparc but only one parcelles_ozae constitue the unites_foncieres.
I noticed this happened only when the parcelles_ozae have the same code_insee, nom_pro, adr_prop, cp_prop and ville_prop.

So when the owner is the same (pro/prop suffix means owner) even if the parcelles_ozae are not next each other : the refparc_list will be constituted of all the refparc of other parcelles_ozae.

For example, on the screenshots : there is only one parcelles_ozae [image: parcelles_ozae] (refparc : BX0095) constituting the unites_foncieres but the refparc_liste references several refparc : [image: unites_foncieres] The good one is here : BX0095 but they are other ones that don't constitute the unites_foncieres.

Do you have a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution :

```
(SELECT string_agg(btrim(parcelles_ozae.refparc::text), ','::text) AS string_agg
    FROM parcelles_ozae
    WHERE st_contains(foo.wkb_geometry, st_pointonsurface(parcelles_ozae.wkb_geometry))) AS refparc_liste
```

I'm doing this SELECT in my main SELECT with the same st_contains I do in the WHERE of the main SELECT.

Here is the full code :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.v_izae_unites_foncieres_14
AS SELECT row_number() OVER () AS ogc_fid,
    foo.code_insee,
    foo.nompro,
    foo.adr_prop,
    foo.cp_prop,
    foo.ville_prop,
    foo.wkb_geometry,
    round(st_area(foo.wkb_geometry)::integer::numeric, 0) AS surface,
    concat(zae.numero_zae, '-', row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY zae.numero_zae ORDER BY zae.ogc_fid)) AS code,
    (SELECT string_agg(btrim(parcelles_ozae.refparc::text), ','::text) AS string_agg
    FROM parcelles_ozae
    WHERE st_contains(foo.wkb_geometry, st_pointonsurface(parcelles_ozae.wkb_geometry))) AS refparc_liste,
    foo.numero_zae
   FROM ( SELECT faa.code_insee,
            faa.nompro,
            faa.adr_prop,
            faa.cp_prop,
            faa.ville_prop,
            faa.numero_zae,
            (st_dump(st_union(faa.wkb_geometry))).geom::geometry(Polygon,2154) AS wkb_geometry,
            array_agg(faa.refparc) AS refparc_liste
           FROM ( SELECT parcelles_ozae.ogc_fid,
                            parcelles_ozae.wkb_geometry,
                            parcelles_ozae.code_insee,
                            parcelles_ozae.nompro,
                            parcelles_ozae.adr_prop,
                            parcelles_ozae.cp_prop,
                            parcelles_ozae.ville_prop,
                            parcelles_ozae.refparc,
                            parcelles_ozae.numero_zae
                   FROM zae zae_1, parcelles_ozae
                   WHERE st_contains(zae_1.wkb_geometry, st_pointonsurface(parcelles_ozae.wkb_geometry))) faa
          GROUP BY faa.nompro, faa.code_insee, faa.adr_prop, faa.cp_prop, faa.ville_prop, faa.numero_zae) foo
     JOIN zae ON foo.numero_zae::text = zae.numero_zae::text;
```

Answer (score 3):

Fields asked and returned by the DB when opening the attribute table, getting feature information, displaying a feature geometry etc are not always the same, and consequently the DB can (and will) execute the query differently, returning rows in different order.

Because the view assigns an ID based on the row number, but without ordering ALL results first, it is possible that the same ID gets assigned to different features on different calls. You click on feature #1, the ID is sent to the DB to get all fields values, but the now feature #1 is a totally different feature.

Change

```sql
SELECT row_number() OVER () AS ogc_fid,
```

for a version setting a definitive order between all results

```sql
SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY layer1.id, layer2.id, layer3.id) AS ogc_fid,
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I really don't get what you mean. 
I don't know which order I need to set to get proper results.
And I think that the ogc_fid isn't used to create the refparc_liste ?

Comment: @JulesBaraton The problem is the computed rowid. If you don't demand that SQL return rows in a certain order (via ORDER BY) it can return in any order that makes "sense". Which means that selecting by rowid (which it the entire purpose of having a rowid) is indeterminant. Which is why JGH is recommending the ORDER BY.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I didn't resolve my problem by SQL with your solutions. 
I get what you mean, but I don't know how to set the ORDER BY properly.

I noticed my problem happened only when the parcelles_ozae have the same code_insee, nom_pro, adr_prop, cp_prop and ville_prop.

So when the owner is the same (pro/prop suffix means owner) even if the parcelles_ozae are not next each other : the refparc_list will be constituted of all the refparc of other parcelles_ozae.

Finally, I manually changed my data set, it wasn't very long.